# How to Sequencing Tests from a Test Suite.

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng

Please help me sequence the tests in a Test Suite. 
I have 2 test classes each having 3 test methods.

**First Class**

```
public class FirstClass  {

@Test(priority =1)
public void FirstMetod()
{
    System.out.println("First Method of First Class");
}


@Test(priority =2)
public void SecondMetod()
{
    System.out.println("Second Method of First Class");
}

@Test(priority =3)
public void ThirdMetod()
{
    System.out.println("Third Method of First Class");
}
}
```

**Second Class**

```
public class SecondClass {

    @Test(priority =1)
    public void FirstMetod()
    {
        System.out.println("First Method of Second Class");
    }


    @Test(priority =2)
    public void SecondMetod()
    {
        System.out.println("Second Method of Second Class");
    }

    @Test(priority =3)
    public void ThirdMetod()
    {
        System.out.println("Third Method of Second Class");
    }
}
```

testng.xml

```
<suite name="Suite">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="sample.testng.FirstClass" />
        <class name="sample.testng.SecondClass" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

The Results are as follows.

```
First Method of First Class
First Method of Second Class
Second Method of First Class
Second Method of Second Class
Third Method of First Class
Third Method of Second Class
```

But I need to run the second class after first class. So the desired results should be.

```
First Method of First Class
Second Method of First Class
Third Method of First Class
First Method of Second Class
Second Method of Second Class
Third Method of Second Class
```

I have tried grouping and depends on methods also, but could not achieve the desired sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `priority` from `@Test` level and change your `testng.xml` file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="sample.testng.FirstClass">
                <methods>
                    <include name="FirstMetod" />
                    <include name="SecondMetod" />
                    <include name="ThirdMetod" />
                </methods>
            </class>
            <class name="sample.testng.SecondClass">
                <methods>
                    <include name="FirstMetod" />
                    <include name="SecondMetod" />
                    <include name="ThirdMetod" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

After changing it, you will get output like this

```
First Method of First Class
Second Method of First Class
Third Method of First Class
First Method of Second Class
Second Method of Second Class
Third Method of Second Class

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```